# api.pro.coinbase.com retrieve historic candles data

Tags: coinbase.com, historical-trade-data, gdax

I am using PHP to retrieve historic candles data from `api.pro.coinbase.com`

```
https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USD/candles?granularity=86400
```

Above URL gets 300 candles. I would like to know how I can get more or less candles.

In bitfinex I can set the number of candles (up to 1000) using limit parameter like this `https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:1D:tBTCUSD/hist?limit=1000`

Answer (score 1):

Im working on the same thing. You have to repeat the request.

For 1000 candles you need to loop the request 3-4 times with different start and end parameters.

I had it working for hole hours but now that I switched to minute granularity the request comes out weird.